# word for act of keeping a knife in front of throat to threaten

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What is word I can use to describe the act of keeping a knife in front of throat to threaten. Can use the word "keep" as in the below sentence?

> She takes a knife and keeps the knife close to Christina's throat.

Comment: If you didn't need to specify proximity to the throat, you could say _She held Christina **at knifepoint**._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually one would say:

> She held a knife at Christina's throat.

You can actually use either *to* or *at* as the preposition.

See [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knife+to+her+throat%2Cknife+at+her+throat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):
[image: Screenshot of Google ngram] ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​